# How to fill a 2d array given values in another class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

EDIT: THERE IS NOTHING ABOUT NULL POINTER. NOT A DUPLICATE -The Null pointer exception is what I get so I know I'm not filling the array right, that's what I'm asking. How do I fill the array?

I am trying to input the values inside of one class into the 2d array declared into another class.

The way it's supposed to work is in the main the nested loop is supposed to supply the values to the other method which is then supposed to input them into the 2d array.

Thanks

Here is main

```
public class Lab1 {
static final int NBPLAYERS = 11;
static final int NBMONTHS = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] month = {"April", "May","June", "July", "August","September"};
    String[] players ={"Colabello","Donaldson","Smoak","Martin","Goins","Encarnacion","Carrera","Tulow    itzki","Pillar","Bautista","Travis"};
    double[][] battingAvg = {
                {0,.368,.300,.224,.386,.268},
        {.319,.306,.269,.287,.324,.296},
        {.229,.310,.213,.191,.203,.262},
        {.197,.327,.239,.256,.138,.213},
        {.276,.236,.172,.240,.314,.279},
        {.205,.225,.303,.241,.407,.279},
        {0,.302,.282,.244,.333,.231},
        {0,0,0,.357,.214,.237},
        {.273,.181,365,.283,.240,.323},
        {.164,.295,.226,.219,.286,.293},
        {.325,.189,.313,.368,0,0}};

    double [][] onBase = {
                {.417,.330,.286,.413,.362,.429},        
        {.370,.373,.322,.370,.408,.403},
        {.372,.333,.275,.283,.243,.324},
        {.367,.362,.329,.322,.263,.300},
        {.323,.278,.221,.286,.442,.347},
        {.258,.333,.382,.384,.460,.411},
        {0,.357,.333,.277,.333,.313},
        {0,0,0,.400,.325,.250},
        {.297,.237,.380,.323,.283,.363},
        {.325,.418,.388,.300,.370,.436},
        {.393,.246,.313,.421,0,0}};

    PlayerStats player;

    BlueJays team = new BlueJays(NBPLAYERS, NBMONTHS);

    for(int iPlayer=0; iPlayer<NBPLAYERS; iPlayer++) {
        for(int iMonth=0; iMonth<NBMONTHS; iMonth++) {
         player = new PlayerStats(players[iPlayer], iMonth, battingAvg[iPlayer][iMonth],onBase[iPlayer][iMonth]);

        team.setPlayerStatsCell(player,iPlayer,iMonth);
    }
    }

    team.getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg();
    team.getHighestOnBase(5);
    team.getLowestBattingAvg(5);
    team.getBestMonth("Bautista");
    team.getBestOverallRecord();
    team.getLowestOnBase();
```

The part of this method that I am trying to use ATM is the

```
PlayerStats setPlayerStatsCell(PlayerStats p, int nbPlayers, int nmMonths)
```

Which should, take the information from main and put it into the 2d array.

```
class BlueJays {

  int nbPlayers;
  int nbMonths;
  int j = 0;
  int highestBattingAvg;
  int highestBattingMonth;
  String highestBattingPlayer;
  int highestOnBase;
  int lowestAvg;
  String lowestAvgPlayer;
  int highestOverall;
  String highestOverallPlayer;
  int lowestOnBase;
  int lowestOnBaseMonth;
  String highestOnBasePlayer;
  double bestOverAllMonth;

  PlayerStats[][] stats;

  public BlueJays(int nbplayers2, int nbmonths2) {
   this.nbPlayers = nbplayers2;
   this.nbMonths = nbmonths2;
   this.stats = new PlayerStats[nbPlayers][nbMonths];
}



PlayerStats setPlayerStatsCell(PlayerStats p, int nbPlayers, int nmMonths) {

for(int i=0; i<nbPlayers; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<nmMonths; j++) {
        stats[i][j]= p;
    }
}
    return p;
}


PlayerStats getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg() {

  j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)   {
    for(j = 0; j<nbMonths; j++) {
        stats[i][j].getAvg();
        if(highestBattingAvg < stats[i][j].getAvg()) {
           highestBattingMonth = stats[i][j].getMonth();
           highestBattingPlayer = stats[i][j].getName();
        }

        System.out.println("Highest average batting player for the month " + highestBattingMonth + " is " + highestBattingPlayer);

        }
    }
    return null;
}

 PlayerStats getHighestOnBase(int month) {
   while(j < nbMonths) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
        stats[i][month].getOnBase();
        if(highestOnBase < stats[i][month].getOnBase()) {
        highestOnBasePlayer =  stats[i][month].getName();
    }

    if (i == nbMonths) {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Highest average onBase player for the month " + month + highestOnBasePlayer);
}
}
return null;
}


public PlayerStats getLowestBattingAvg(int month) {
j = 0;
  while(j < nbMonths) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
        stats[i][month].getOnBase();
    if(lowestAvg > stats[i][month].getAvg()) {
        lowestAvgPlayer =  stats[i][month].getName();
    }
    if (i == nbMonths) {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println("Lowest average batting player for the month " + month + " is " + lowestAvgPlayer);
  }
return null;
}

 PlayerStats getBestMonth(String player) {
    j = 0;
  while(j < nbMonths) {
for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
    stats[i][j].getBoth();

    if(bestOverAllMonth > stats[i][j].getAvg() && stats[i][j].getName().contains(player)) {
         bestOverAllMonth =  stats[i][j].getBoth();
    }
    if (i == nbMonths) {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println("Best month for the player " + player + " is " + bestOverAllMonth);
}
 return null;
  }

 public String getBestOverallRecord() {
  j = 0;
while(j < nbMonths) {
   for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
       stats[i][j].getBoth();
    if(highestOverall < stats[i][j].getBoth()) {
        highestOverallPlayer =  stats[i][j].getName();
    }
    if (i == nbMonths) {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println("Highest overall record is " + highestOverallPlayer);
}
   return null;
}

 public PlayerStats getLowestOnBase() {
   j = 0;
while(j < nbMonths) {
   for(int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)  {
    stats[i][j].getOnBase();
    if(lowestOnBase > stats[i][j].getOnBase()) {
        double lowestOnBase =  stats[i][j].getOnBase();
        if(lowestOnBase > 0) {
            lowestAvgPlayer = stats[i][j].getName();
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    if (i == nbMonths) {
        j++;
        i = 0;
    } 
 }
 }
  System.out.println("Lowest On Base is  " + lowestOnBase);
 }
return null;
  }
}
```

Here's the PlayerStats code

```
class PlayerStats {

private String name;
private int month;
private double battAvg, onBase;

public PlayerStats(String name, int month, double battingAvg, double onBase2) {
    this.name = name;
    this.month = month;
    this.battAvg = battingAvg;
    this.onBase =  onBase2;
}

public String getName() {
    return name; 
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(int month) {
    this.month = month; 
}


public double getAvg() {
    return battAvg;
}

public double getOnBase() {
    return onBase;
}

public double getBoth() {
    return battAvg + onBase;
  }
}
```

And the exception it throws is a Null Pointer, which the array is not filling.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BlueJays.getHighestSingleMonthBattingAvg(BlueJays.java:52)
at Lab1.main(Lab1.java:52)
Highest average batting player for the month 0 is null
Highest average batting player for the month 0 is null
Highest average batting player for the month 0 is null
Highest average batting player for the month 0 is null
Highest average batting player for the month 0 is null
```

Comment: I remember seeing the same question here yesterday and it still lacks of PlayerStats source code :-)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Inserting Data into a 2d array from a different class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811439/inserting-data-into-a-2d-array-from-a-different-class). Please [don't just delete and re-ask the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255955/reopen-vs-delete-and-post-it-again). Editing puts it into a queue to be reviewed and possibly reopened.

Comment: @resueman - That one was taken down, nobody could answer it.

Comment: How about posting the call stack with the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setPlayerStatsCell` function makes no sense in context. Try this one:

```
PlayerStats setPlayerStatsCell(PlayerStats p, int nbPlayer, int nmMonth)
{
    stats[nbPlayer][nmMonth] = p;
    return p;
}
```

The error was caused by the old one not being able to set the last row and column of the table.

Comment: Thank man! I have another question if your around, my other return types, are all Null, What could i make them?

Comment: If you don't actually need return values, make the functions `void` and then you won't need them at all, but as most of your member functions begin with "get", why not return the stat you're printing?.